# Problem setting series values in VBA SeriesCollection

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax for assigning a SeriesCollection value. I'm trying to set it like this:

```
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range(Cells(4, tCols + 14), Cells(4, tCols + 12 + z)).Address
```

That address is the correct range for what I'm trying to use, but I'm getting tripped up when trying to assign it to a SeriesCollection value. Could someone help me with the correct syntax? Thanks so much

Full code below:

```
Dim advStatObj As ChartObject
Dim advStatChart As Chart

Set advStatObj = Sheets("AdvStats").ChartObjects.Add(Top:=Cells(7, tCols + 13).Top, Left:=Cells(7, tCols + 13).Left, Width:=800, Height:=500)

Set advStatChart = advStatObj.Chart

With advStatChart
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).name = "=""Projected"""
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range(Cells(4, tCols + 14), Cells(4, tCols + 12 + z)).Address
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).name = "=""Current"""
        'goes on
End With
```

Comment: Try `"=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range(Cells(4, tCols + 14), Cells(4, tCols + 12 + z)).Address`

Comment: Perfect. I didn't realize the sheet name was a requirement.